# column sorting in ascending and descending order without using linq

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid view called membersgridview
with columns

```
memberaccountid
memberaccountname
ordername
orderid
```

how do i get the column sorting....

if i click on the column header column values in datagrid view will be sorted in ascending order..

if i click on the column header again the column values will be sorted in descending order..

i am doing windows applications using c#..

I have done the column sorting using linq , i want to do the column sorting without using linq ..

would anyone pls suggest me any ideas and any code snippets that will really helps me..

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do it without LINQ?

Comment: @svick thats my team lead order... i dont know why he dint like linq..

Comment: You could use this code in the columnclick event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx

Comment: @zenwalker many thanks i have tried that code but it will always goes into this condition    if (newColumn == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a single column and try again.",
            "Error: Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

Comment: Does this help this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);

Comment: Wasn't there just a simple AllowColumnSorting property on datagrids? I remember this as out-of-the-box behaviour.

Comment: show the code you are using right now to load the data and sort, show the LINQ and we will see how it can be done without that LINQ. No Crystal balls here!!

Comment: @GertArnold Many thanks I have done exactly same as you posted here and post it as answer i will accept ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid doesn't sort as-is, I think you could sort the datasource of the grid, probably some collection object, by feeding in an `IComparer` depending on the clicked column and sort direction